# Do bees make honey from fallen fruit?

Tags: entomology

I know bees make honey from nectar, and I know they drink the juice of fallen fruit, but do they actually make honey from fruit, or do they only eat from it for themselves?

Comment: Well, they do, but I'm still looking for scientific backup. They also make honey from maple syrup, corn syrup, sugarwater, molasses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The substances that bees consume do end up in honey. There was a high-profile case in Brooklyn in 2010 ([*The Mystery of the Red Bees of Red Hook*](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/30/nyregion/30bigcity.html?_r=0)) where bees from several hives began producing red honey after feeding on dyed maraschino cherry juice from a local factory.

A follow-up article from 2015 ([*How Bees Revealed a Pot Farm Beneath the Maraschino Cherries*](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/03/03/how-bees-revealed-a-pot-farm-beneath-the-maraschino-cherries.html)) claims that the substance they began producing was not honey but “red gunk”; however, that may have been editorial license.

[image: A “honeycomb” from Mr. Selig’s hives. Credit Ozier Muhammad/The New York Times]

Comment: Another proof/example was in France: https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/10/pictures/121011-blue-honey-honeybees-animals-science/